# Find first occurence of value in group using dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

How do i find the first occurence of a certain value, within a group using `dplyr`.

The following code gives the desired result, but it I'm wondering if there is a shorter way to do it.

Also, I am worried that `group_by` or `mutate`, or some other function might do implicit rearrangement of the rows, don't know if this could be an issue?

```
mtcars   %>% select( cyl, carb) %>% group_by( cyl ) %>%

   mutate( "occurence_of_4" =  carb == 4 )  %>%

   dplyr::arrange( cyl )  %>%

   group_by( cyl, occurence_of_4)  %>%

   mutate( "count" = 1:n(),
           "first_4_in_cyl_group"  = ifelse( occurence_of_4==TRUE & count==1, TRUE, FALSE))
```

The variable first_4_in_cyl_group is `TRUE` for the first occurence of "4" in each cylinder group, `FALSE` otherwise:

```
Source: local data frame [32 x 5]
Groups: cyl, occurence_of_4

   cyl carb occurence_of_4 count first_4_in_cyl_group
1    4    1          FALSE     1                FALSE
2    4    2          FALSE     2                FALSE
3    4    2          FALSE     3                FALSE
4    4    1          FALSE     4                FALSE
5    4    2          FALSE     5                FALSE
6    4    1          FALSE     6                FALSE
7    4    1          FALSE     7                FALSE
8    4    1          FALSE     8                FALSE
9    4    2          FALSE     9                FALSE
10   4    2          FALSE    10                FALSE
11   4    2          FALSE    11                FALSE
12   6    4           TRUE     1                 TRUE
13   6    4           TRUE     2                FALSE
14   6    1          FALSE     1                FALSE
15   6    1          FALSE     2                FALSE
16   6    4           TRUE     3                FALSE
17   6    4           TRUE     4                FALSE
18   6    6          FALSE     3                FALSE
19   8    2          FALSE     1                FALSE
20   8    4           TRUE     1                 TRUE
21   8    3          FALSE     2                FALSE
22   8    3          FALSE     3                FALSE
23   8    3          FALSE     4                FALSE
24   8    4           TRUE     2                FALSE
25   8    4           TRUE     3                FALSE
26   8    4           TRUE     4                FALSE
27   8    2          FALSE     5                FALSE
28   8    2          FALSE     6                FALSE
29   8    4           TRUE     5                FALSE
30   8    2          FALSE     7                FALSE
31   8    4           TRUE     6                FALSE
32   8    8          FALSE     8                FALSE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of modifications:

1. Remove the first `mutate` step by creating the "occurence_of_4" variable within the `group_by`
2. `ifelse` is not needed as the output will be "TRUE/FALSE"

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   mtcars %>%
        select(cyl, carb) %>%
        group_by(cyl, occurence_of_4= carb==4) %>% 
        arrange(cyl) %>%
        mutate(count= row_number(), 
            first_4_in_cyl_group = occurence_of_4 & count==1)
   ```

Answer (score 15):

You may use `!duplicated`.

```
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, carb) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(first_4 = carb == 4 & !duplicated(carb == 4))  %>%
  arrange(cyl)
```

Comment: Love this - really efficient for the use case (and my use case).  It's really clean when you already have the item you're trying to find the first of as a logical value.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of grouping it is enough to arrange by cyl and carb. With lag you can check the previous value.

mtcars database doesn't have an ID column, so if you are rearranging rows you could add them with add_rownames (as docendodiscimus suggested in comments).

```
mtcars   %>% 
  select( cyl, carb ) %>%
  add_rownames() %>%
  arrange(cyl, carb) %>%
  mutate(
    isfirst = (carb == 4 & (is.na(lag(carb)) | lag(carb) != 4))) %>%
  filter(isfirst)
```

The result:

```
#      rowname cyl carb isfirst
# 1  Mazda RX4   6    4    TRUE
# 2 Duster 360   8    4    TRUE
```

Comment: You are missing the grouping that's required to reproduce the desired result, no?

Comment: @docendodiscimus I am not sure why grouping is used. It is possible that I don't understand the desired output, but arrange should be enough as I see it.

Comment: Compare the output of your code with the last column of the desired result. Your code produces more TRUE entries than expected

Comment: It is OK if arranged by cyl and carb.

Comment: You are right. (+1) Btw, you could use `add_rownames("id")` inside the dplyr chain.

Comment: Thanks! Agree - `add_rownames` is way more elegant.