# Determining the first occurence of a value by group and its position within the group

Tags: r

I would like to know per group in the column 'Participants' when the value '1' occurs for the first time in the column 'Signal' (by Participants). The count of the value '1' should refer to the group.

Here is an example data frame

```
> dfInput <- data.frame(Participants=c( 'A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C'), Signal=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,0))
> dfInput

  Participants Signal
1            A      0
2            A      1
3            A      1
4            B      0
5            B      0
6            B      0
7            B      1
8            C      1
9            C      0
```

And here is the output I am looking for:

```
> dfOutput <-data.frame(Participants=c( 'A','B','C'), RowNumberofFirst1=c(2, 4, 1))
> dfOutput


  Participants RowNumberofFirst1
1            A          2
2            B          4
3            C          1
```

The problem is somewhat similar to this: [Find first occurence of value in group using dplyr mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273012/find-first-occurence-of-value-in-group-using-dplyr-mutate)
Yet, I could not adapt it accordingly, to create my output df

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)
dfInput %>% 
  group_by(Participants) %>% 
  summarise(RowNumberofFirst1 = which(Signal == 1)[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R via `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Signal~Participants, dfInput, function(i)which(i == 1)[1])

#  Participants Signal
#1            A      2
#2            B      4
#3            C      1
```

Comment: a variant:  `aggregate(Signal~Participants, dfInput, function(x) match(1,x))`

Answer (score 1):

```
dfInput <- data.frame(Participants=c( 'A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C'), 
                      Signal=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,0))

library(dplyr)

dfInput %>%
  group_by(Participants) %>%                             # for each Participant
  summarise(NumFirst1 = min(row_number()[Signal == 1]))  # get the minimum number of row where signal equals 1

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Participants NumFirst1
#   <fct>            <int>
# 1 A                    2
# 2 B                    4
# 3 C                    1
```

In case you want to return the row (i.e. all column values) that you've identified, you can use this:

```
set.seed(5)

dfInput <- data.frame(Participants=c( 'A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C'), 
                      Signal=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,0),
                      A = sample(c("C","D","F"),9, replace = T),
                      B = sample(c("N","M","K"),9, replace = T))

library(dplyr)

dfInput %>%
  group_by(Participants) %>%
  filter(row_number() == min(row_number()[Signal == 1])) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Participants Signal A     B    
#   <fct>         <dbl> <fct> <fct>
# 1 A                 1 F     N    
# 2 B                 1 D     N    
# 3 C                 1 F     M
```

So, in this case you use `filter` to return, for each participant, the row that is equal to the minimum row number where `Signal` is 1.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well! I also added as.data.frame() to get a dataframe output.

Comment: What I now would like to know is what the values are in two other columns for the  row that was identified. So let us say the dfInput has two more columns C5 & C6 with different entries. I now want to display the content of these in my output dataframe. So, the output would be:
'code'
# Participants NumFirst1  C5           C6
#1 A                2                Sydney    Melbourne
#2 B                4                Brisbane  Melbourne    
#3 C                1                Perth       Perth

i.e. the city names occur in the rows identified in the dfInput

Comment: I think I got what you mean. I've updated my answer. Have a look and let me know.

Comment: Thank you, yes this works (sorry for the messy formatting in the prior comment). I realized that in the outcome dataframe it would be handy to know, which RowNumber the Signal occured. For instance, for Participants Group A, it is row 2, for Participants Group B, it is row 4. Is there a way to add this information as an additional column?

Comment: You can add `mutate(row = row_number())` before the `filter` in order to keep the position of the rows you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`:

```
 dfInput%>%
   group_by(Participants)%>%
   mutate(max=cumsum(Signal),
          RowNumberofFirst1=row_number())%>%
   filter(max==1)%>%
   top_n(-1,RowNumberofFirst1)%>%
   select(Participants,RowNumberofFirst1)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Participants [3]
  Participants RowNumberofFirst1
  <fct>                    <int>
1 A                            2
2 B                            4
3 C                            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with base `R`:

```
dfInput <- data.frame(Participants=c( 'A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C'), Signal=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,0))
tapply(dfInput$Signal, dfInput$Participants, FUN=function(x) min(which(x==1)))
# > tapply(dfInput$Signal, dfInput$Participants, FUN=function(x) min(which(x==1)))
# A B C 
# 2 4 1
```

If you want a dataframe you can do:

```
first1 <- tapply(dfInput$Signal, dfInput$Participants, FUN=function(x) min(which(x==1)))
data.frame(Participants=names(first1), f=first1)
```

Here is a variant with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(dfInput)
dfInput[, which(Signal==1)[1], "Participants"]
```